# Are you aware of unusual tag choice offerings?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

I am working at learning iOS, and without exception all of my recent questions have related to iOS / Xcode / Objective-C / iOS Simulator / iPhone / iPad. I have asked questions about web development / HTML / CSS / ..., but not recently. I want to learn Android, but to date I have never asked a question about Android development.

The list of suggested tags for my post are slightly puzzling; "ios" is one frequent suggestion for my tags, but some of the time "android" is suggested, and I am frequently offered "html" and "css".

I'm not sure whether tags are proposed based on a user's entire posting history, but whatever the reason, some of the tags leave me puzzled, and I thought it was worth a post here.

Is the behavior I have seen the intended and desired behavior?

Comment: The title reads all too amusingly like a spam email subject.

Comment: Anyway, where exactly are you seeing these tag suggestions? In the question submission form, on your front page, or elsewhere?

Comment: In the question submission form; there is a text input to input tags, and below that a clickable set of suggested tags.

Comment: I think the suggested tags are related to how often the tags are used together with the tags you've already entered. Or related to tags you often use. I often get many versions of VB recommended to me when I enter in the asp.net tag for instance (without ever getting involved with vb on this site)

Comment: You are taking tag suggestions way too seriously. It's a blind guess by a piece of software based on some very superficial analysis. While I wouldn't be surprised to learn that the SO team has been working on an artificial conciousness to scan, comprehend and make intelligent decisions on new questions, I haven't seen any notifications about its release. Maybe they're waiting for an April 1, 2014 rollout.

Comment: @boltclock interestingly, my spam filter didn't catch this one (though it does give me a suggestion as to which heuristic to add)

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you're talking about the suggested tags you get when you are finished writing a question.

Those tags are decided upon based on an analysis of the text in your question - if you say PHP one or two times, [php](/questions/tagged/php) will probably be suggested. If you say Android a lot, [android](/questions/tagged/android) will most likely be in the suggestions.

The suggestions have, as far as I know, nothing to do with your past history - they just have to do with the text in your question's title and body.